# Rails ActiveRecord Nullifying dependent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have a `Contact` record that has a reference to self like the following:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one    :inverse,
    :class_name => "Contact",
    :dependent => :nullify
end
```

so two contact records can be associated through an `inverse_id`

I am expecting upon deleting one of the records, the inverse record should have its `inverse_id` attribute set to `null`. But that's not the case.

I have tried both with `object.destroy` and without `:dependent => :nullify` and with `object.delete` and `:dependent => :nullify`. None works.

thoughts?

Comment: What is the Rails version?